# (Reactjs) How to submit the file immediately after selected the file

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to submit an image using input field without a submit button. When the file is selected, it will be submitted automatically. I am thinking doing it like this:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

const updateState = (e) => {
  setImage(e.target.files[0]);
}

const submitFile = async () => {
  ...submit the file...
}
 
<input accept='image/*' type='file' onChange={() => { updateState(); submitFile(); }} />
```

I really want to know is there a better way to do this? Because I not feeling right about this, it seems not very programmatic.

Comment: you can do it all in one function, execute your request onSelect the files, also I think you don't need the state while you will use the event and send the files directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `useEffect` for updated state

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(image){
       submitFile()   
    }     
},[image])
<input accept='image/*' type='file' onChange={() =>  updateState()} />
```

or you can call it in update state

```
const updateState = (e) => {
  setImage(e.target.files[0]);
  submitFile(e.target.files[0])
}
```